# How can i save screenshot image to phone storage in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, save, storage, screenshot

This code run successfully but didn't find screenshots in android emulator storage. whats the problem? is there need any change for saving screenshots in phone storage?

```js
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native SnapShot!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={
            () => {
            captureScreen({
              format: "jpg",
              quality: 0.8
            })
            .then(
              uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
              error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
            );
          }
          }
          title="capture"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Capture"
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: captureScreen function which module you are using?

Comment: import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";

Comment: if you have any alternative solution then can you plz share any example?
i want to capture screenshot with a button and want to save that in phone storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following module for saving image in local storage https://github.com/francisco-sanchez-molina/react-native-store-photos-album

```
import CameraRollExtended from 'react-native-store-photos-album'
```

---

```
<Button
  onPress = {
    () => {
      captureScreen({
          format: "jpg",
          quality: 0.8
        })
        .then(
          uri => {
            CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll({
              uri: uri,
              album: 'Name'
            }, 'photo')
          },
          error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
        );
    }
  }
/>
```

Comment: Also, there is react native default function to save in camera roll. please check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#savetocameraroll

Comment: I need a another help on this module. I need the path/location of saved image because I want to attach it to a mail. Is there any way to get that uri?

Comment: You got URI so I think this will help you. No idea how but may be.

Comment: how to change the path of saved image to something else like DCIM/test/0/1.jpg ?